# Check from within bash script that autocompletion is initialized

Tags: linux, bash, shell, autocomplete, sh

I'm looking for a method to check from within my shell script that script specific completion have been initialized by user using `complete -F ...`

I want this check to print out an advice on how to initialize the completion like:

`Warning: Auto completion is not initialized. Please run : source ....; complete -F ...`

The problem is that the script,being run in a sub-shell has no information about "complete" environment of the parent shell where user is working.

So `complete -p| grep my-script-name` never return any result.

User is expected to run "source" and "complete" commands or add them into his .bashrc manually, because we're working on a server where we have no access to the bash completion system directory.

Alternatively if you know a method of initializing(and not only checking) the auto-complete from within the script, I would happily accept it.

Comment: You might try asking this on the [bash-help](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/) mailing list if you don't get an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way your script can have access to such information for the parent shell is if it is included instead of executed as a sub-shell.  Rather than instructing your users they can include some configuration, you can design your script so it works whether it is run or included.

Then you can simply inform your users that if they want completion enabled they need to include your script rather than run it as an executable script (with instuctions to use source or . as you wish).

However, in this case, I would be inclined to either add this information in documentation or add it into a banner which is always displayed (but can be disabled with an option switch like -q), rather than support two modes of running the script (since the gain is so small).

Answer (score 0):

Either you want every user to use bash completion (which I don't think is good, for example I prefer to have it turned off), or let users decide themselves, but having them this message printed out on each TABTAB is a threat, don't you think?

I'd put into /etc/bash.bashrc what you think every user should run.

Comment: 1)I've specified in the question, that we have NO write access to the system directories. It's a server. 2) I don't want the notification upon TABTAB, I want it when the script is invoked by user. I just want to tell him, he can set up the completion which will help him to work with the script.3)Users DO want it - I got a requirement to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't get that (the description is a little messy). So if you can't change anything except for your own user, how do you expect to change completion for all users?

Comment: Not for all but rather for each :) He/she has an option of running "source ..." manually or inserting this command into their private .bashrc. But,of course,the user should be aware of such a possibility and I just wanted to print an announce for him.

Comment: How's that different? Re-formulated: If all that you have write access to is your own account, how do you expect to change other users' configuration?

Comment: I think that misunderstands his question, unfortunately I think the solution is that security principles on linux prevent him doing what he wants.  He would like to *detect* autocomplete in the parent shell, and then *inform* users that they have the privilege to change other user's configurations.  I think this is a reasonable request.  I will post a workaround as an answer.

Comment: sorry, "other user's configurations" should read "their own configurations", don't know what I did there in editing!